# Does $\left\lbrace 1- \frac{1}{5-n^2} : n \in \Bbb N\right\rbrace$ admit a maximum and minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Does the following set admit a maximum and minimum? $$A= \left\lbrace 1- \frac{1}{5-n^2} : n \in \Bbb N\right\rbrace$$

---

First, I've plot some of the set elements

$$A = \left\lbrace \frac{3}{4},0, \frac{5}{4}, \frac{12}{11}, \frac{21}{20}, \frac{32}{31}, \dots \right\rbrace$$

We can observe that when $n \in \mathbb{N}$ increases the set elements seem to tend to $1$. We know that if the sequence $$A_{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{5-n^2}$$ converges then is bounded. Then I proceeded to calculate its limit.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} A_{n}=1$$

The proof of this I'm going to not write it but was done. Then, if $A_{n}$ is monotonically decreasing (as I assumed) the limit is equal to $\inf A_{n} = 1$ and then prove by doing the following:

$A_{n} \geq A_{n+1}$

$2n -4 \geq -5$

$n \geq -1/2$

Then, it's true     $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

I'm confused because we can see from the elements of the set that actually for $n=1$ we've $a_1=0$ which seems to be infimum but minimum as well.  In general, you can have more than one infimum. But then how can I show that the minimum is actually $a_1=0$? How can I show which one is the maximum?

Comment: +1 : Very nice presentation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - it is bounded. However, it is monotonically decreasing as long as $n>2$, meaning you don't know what happens at $a_1,a_2$ (a-priori). Now, we can take a look at the sequence $a_n=1-\frac{1}{5-n^2}$ from $a_3$ and on, namely we look at $a_{n-2}$.

It obviously converges to $1$ still and is monotonically decreasing, so the infimum of $\{1-\frac{1}{5-n^2}:n>2\}$ is $1$. However, we still have to consider $a_1,a_2$. In this case you know that $a_2=0$, so the infimum (in this case minimum) is $0$. As for the supremum (and in this case maximum) we have that $a_3=\frac{5}{4}\geq a_n$ for every $n>2$ and $a_3>a_2,a_1$ and therefore $a_3$ is the maximum.

Edited extra explanation:
$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{(5-n^2)(5-(n+1)^2)}$. Since the numerator is alwasy $\geq0$, $a_{n+1}-a_n\geq0$ iff $(5-n^2)(5-(n+1)^2)>0$, meaning $5> n^2,(n+1)^2$ or $5<n^2,(n+1)^2$ which shows that $a_2$ is problematic and has to be taken care of separately.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the answer. Clarifies a lot things.